# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable in cv2.Normalize

Tags: python, linux, opencv, machine-learning, raspberry-pi

I compiled this program which extracts features from a cell image and tells whether or not it is cancerous using randomforestclassifier on python-3.5. I made it on windows 8.1 where it is working perfectly. But its not working on my raspberry pi which have raspbian stretch os. here is the code which show error.

```
def colorRatioMean(rgbImage):     
  R = cv2.normalize(rgbImage[:,:,0].astype('double'), None, 0, 255, 
  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
  G = cv2.normalize(rgbImage[:,:,1].astype('double'), None, 0, 255, 
  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
  B = cv2.normalize(rgbImage[:,:,2].astype('double'), None, 0, 255, 
  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

Above shown code is the part of my class which extracts features.

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Cancer_Detector/image.py", line 117, in <module>
  r, g, b = features.colorRatioMean(image)
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Cancer_Detector/image.py", line 24, in colorRatioMean
  R = cv2.normalize(rgbImage[:,:,0].astype('double'), 0, 255, 
  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Your `rgbImage` turns out to be null. Review the code to see the origin of this variable, and check if the image is loading properly.

Comment: The lines from above listings do not match:
`R = cv2.normalize(rgbImage[:,:,0].astype('double'), None, 0, 255, 
  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)` 
and
`R = cv2.normalize(rgbImage[:,:,0].astype('double'), 0, 255, 
  cv2.NORM_MINMAX)`
'None' is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The image you are passing to function is a null image. To see the type of a null image:

rgbImage = cv2.imread("some_non_existing_image.jpg")
print ("Image type: ",type(rgbImage))

the result will be:
   'Image type: ', type 'NoneType'

To resolve the problem test the image type before passaing it to the function
something like this where the function is beeing called:

if rgbImage is None:
  #
  # do not pass it to function, perhaps by pass
  #
  print ("Null imagem")
  pass # Only for example
else:
  colorRatioMean(rgbImage)


See: The "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" is because there is nothing in it
```